# How to insert Documents to MongoDB stitch from client app without authentication (as admin)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-stitch, mongodb-authentication

i want to store users TTL(Time to live) data to DataBase even his not confirmed the email and not authenticated.
So after confirmation i will set 'activated:true' and keep the user data.
i'm using a Reactjs app with stitch.

Comment: You seem a little confused on this. There is a **big** difference between "authorized with your application" and **"your application authorizing with the database"**. The two are completely unrelated, and **"your application should always authorize with the database"** unless you want someone to stumble across your database and **delete all your data**. You really seem to be talking about *end user authentication*, which has nothing to do with connecting to MongoDB. Or Stitch for that matter.

Comment: yes i'm with you, So how can i do this, to write in database as admin from client app.

Comment: Could you elaborate the question with case examples , document examples, and code examples that you've tried please ? It sounds like you could just create a Stitch function from React that pushes data to a collection, but clarification on what you're trying to do would be helpful for others to help you